# ToString() method return different result based on object

Tags: c#, tostring

I am working on an app where you can create a Subscription and you can either choose an Individual or Company Subscription which are both classes. But I am having some trouble with the override ToString(). Is it possible to have some kind of an if statement that can say if the object is create as an Individual Subscription return the string formatted for an Individual, else return the one for the Company. Here is my code to make it clearer:

```
public class Subscription: ObservingClass
{

    private IndividualApplicant _individualApplicant;
    private CompanyApplicant _companyApplicant;
    private SubsAmount _subsAmount;

    public IndividualApplicant IndividualApplicant
    {
        get { return _individualApplicant; }
        set
        {
            _individualApplicant = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public CompanyApplicant CompanyApplicant
    {
        get { return _companyApplicant; }
        set
        {
            _companyApplicant = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public SubsAmount SubsAmount
    {
        get { return _subsAmount; }
        set
        {
            _subsAmount = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Subscription()
    {
        IndividualApplicant = new IndividualApplicant();
        CompanyApplicant =  new CompanyApplicant();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Subscription Amount: " + SubsAmount + "\n" + IndividualApplicant.ToString();
    }


}
```

Comment: You can do whatever you want inside the `ToString` method. This question isn't clear enough to be able to help you further though. How can I tell the difference between an individual and a company subscription, when looking at the properties and fields of that object?

Comment: The difference is on the UI. If you click on Individual it re-directs you to the one in the Individual and same thing for Company. But when you add the object to an ObservableCollection the information should be formatted in different ways

Comment: So the object doesn't know if it is a individual or a company subscription?

Comment: Well, the subscription is supposed to be defined as Individual or Company when the user decided on the UI. He has the two options. and when he click Add for example and he has chosen Individual, the object added to the ObservableCollection is an IndividualSubscription and the ToString would display the formatted information about an IndividualSubcription.

Comment: So then implement the `ToString` method of `IndividualSubscription` different from that of a company.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is much worse than that.

> can either choose an Individual or Company Subscription which are both classes.

This would indicate inhertance - 2 classes (IndividualSubscription, CompanySubscription) - and then... where is the problem? both override Tostring as they want and need.

But your class model is extremely bad.

> public CompanyApplicant CompanyApplicant
>       {
>           get { return _companyApplicant; }
>           set
>           {
>               _companyApplicant = value;
>               OnPropertyChanged();
>           }
>       }

WTF? THat should be Applicant - a CompanySubscription may throw an ArgumentExcveption when an IndivdualApplicant is inserted, but it makes little sense and totally convolutes all logic to have different properties for them depending on subtype.

Answer (score 1):

> create a Subscription and you can
>   either choose an Individual or Company Subscription which are both
>   classes

Then your `Subscription` class should look like this..

```
public class Subscription : ObservingClass
{
    private Applicant _applicant;
    public Applicant Applicant
    {
        get
        {
            return _applicant;
        }
        set
        {
            _applicant = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public Subscription(Applicant applicant)
    {
        Applicant = applicant;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Subscription Amount: " + SubsAmount + "\n" + Applicant.ToString();
    }

    private SubsAmount _subsAmount
    public SubsAmount SubsAmount
    {
        get { return _subsAmount; }
        set
        {
            _subsAmount = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

With this, `Subscription` only knows that it has an `Applicant` which is an `abstract` class (or make it an `interface` if you like)

Now, `IndividualApplicant` and `CompanyApplicant` should inherit `Applicant`.

From there, override `ToString` for both the `IndividualApplicant` and `CompanyApplicant`